# Is there a supported hardware list for elementary OS?

Tags: hardware

Curious if there is a list of hardware successfully running elementary OS.

Reason I ask is because I have 2 MacBook pros, on the newer one, my elementary OS install [usb](/questions/tagged/usb) stick loads into a glorious looking desktop, yet the cursor won't move nor is the keyboard responding.  Yet when I load the same stick into a slightly older MacBook Pro, every thing works perfectly.

So here I am, exciting to dig in, wondering if I could buy an older refurbished iMac to run elementary.

If there is a list, I'd like to participate.  If not, I am curious if anyone else is interested. Seems to me would be invaluable for increasing rate of adoption and growing a happy user base.

Comment: Hi user, welcome to eOS SE. Your participation is much appreciated. I have made some changes on your post to help it get found easily and make it look better though your choice of words and format DO describe your problem well.

Comment: Thx hasan I see you have added a space between elementary and os.  I had removed specifically because I thought it would help people find it amongst the elementary noise :)

Comment: I have deleted my answer releasing that did not provide clear solution to the question which I failed to understand earlier. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not.  Hopefully someone will correct me soon.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15297)

Comment: Hasan, this is a yes / no question.  If you think the answer is yes, please link to the list.

Comment: I do apologize for that, it was a mistake. My bad. It was an accidental act. I am sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

This is far from official, and in fact is Arch Linux based but is reasonably comprehensive for many different vendors - shows if there are any compatibility issues with Linux modules etc

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Laptop/Apple

Comment: elementary is based on ubuntu and the newest Mac in that list is 5 years old.

Answer (score 0):

Since Elementary is built on Ubuntu, your best bet would probably be to use the [Ubuntu Certified Hardware list](https://certification.ubuntu.com/). Insofar as there's a difference between Elementary and Ubuntu in terms of driver support, it's going to be a pretty minimal difference.

Ubuntu also has a bigger user community; see if the same issue exists with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a USB stick, and if it does, see if that community can help you.

Comment: https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/ does not even list apple. While the image is of a laptop, the list is for desktops and there is no list for laptops

Comment: The third column is for laptops; 311 from Dell, 94 from Lenovo, and 80 from HP. Apple is probably not listed because it's not certified.